# Writing a Shell Script to ssh into remote cluster and setup Jupyter notebook instance in a separate compute node

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I am trying to automate a quite tedious process that I have to do before I start work each time (or after each connection drop). I am trying to run a shell script that automates this whole process. However, during this process I have to ssh into multiple machines. Here is the flow:

1. I first open a terminal window in my macbook and log into the remote server. I have the ssh config file and password setup so I only type:

```
[user@local]$ ssh hostname-alias
```

2. Then it takes a few seconds to log into the cluster. When I am in, I then use the `srun` command in the remote machine to allocate resources in cluster [linux]:

```
[user@remote]$ srun -p qTRDGPU -A PSYC0002 -v -n1 --pty --mem=16g --gres=gpu:gforce:1 /bin/bash
```

3. It takes a few seconds to assign me a compute node, say the node being: `user@assigned-node` and automatically logs me in there. I then start a jupyter notebook instance in that node using:

```
[user@assigned-node]$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888
```

I keep the above running in that terminal window.

4. Now, I open a ***separate terminal window***. In that window in the local machine I connect and listen to that port using:

```
[user@local]$ ssh -N -f -L localhost:7777:localhost:8888 user@assigned.edu
```

With these commands the process ends, and I want to condense these commands into a single script. The issue I faced is that when I am writing a shell script the script only runs at the local machine and after the first ssh command the rest wont run. How can I run all these commands with a single script in the required local machine and remote nodes?

Thanks a lot for reading and for your help!

EDIT:
I only wrote so far as:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh remote-alias
srun -p qTRDGPU -A PSYC0002 -v -n1 --pty --mem=16g --gres=gpu:gforce:1 /bin/bash
```

However, the 2nd command won't run in the remote, so I am looking into how to run some parts of my script in local. Then the next command into remote, then the next into another assigned remote node and finally the 4th command into my local machine again in a separate terminal window. Thanks

Comment: I do not know the name of the machine `user@assigned.edu`. So if I include command `hostname` after the `srun` command it will print out the hostname I am hoping. How do I catch that and use that dynamically in the final command?

Comment: Ahh - right - I'm not sure how to grab that info to the local machine, but I'll look into it. Hopefully another SO user can advise further

Comment: sounds like you need to use tools like [tag:expect] (for Tcl) or [tag:pexpect] (for Python). or try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you prefer shell.

Comment: @Rio1210 I am trying to write a bash script to do exactly what your question is about. Have you been able to write a script to perform all these tedious steps with one script? I would love to hear how you have progressed on this issue! :)

Comment: @Rio1210 I have not yet been able to accomplish this with a bash script, but (I work on a mac) I was able to write an apple script that does all this for me and prompts for input (port number and assigned compute node). If that would help you as well, I a happy to share!

Comment: Hey Emily, that’s awesome! I didn’t actually solve this issue. However I ended up using VS code remote development and around the time I asked the question they released a nice Jupyter notebook interface that solved all my issues. I just needed to setup my ssh config once and that was it. However, I am interested to learn how you solved it! If you have some time could you write it up as an answer? Ill accept it as the correct solution. Thanks for reaching out.